# GoogleMaps myLocation marker(blue dot) is disappearing on iOS 13.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios, ios13

I am using the GoogleMap pod in my app. I have been facing an issue with the mylocation marker disappearing and the only fix is to Reset the location & Privacy in the iPhone settings app.

OS version: iOS 13.1
GoogleMaps version: 3.1.0
Xcode version: 10.1

**Steps to reproduce**
1. Launch app
2. Select permission "Allow while using"
3. myLocation marker is visible
4. Quit and Launch the app
5. myLocation marker disappears
6. Reset the location & Privacy in the iPhone settings app
7. myLocation marker is visible
8. Quit and Launch the app
9. myLocation marker disappears

**Sample Code**
I set the value of "isMyLocationEnabled" in CLLocationManagerDelegate method

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

    if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse || status == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways {
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Do I need to update the pod for iOS 13 and create a build using the latest Xcode?
Is it possible that I can apply a fix using Xcode 10.1? I want to avoid the latest Xcode migration/conversions.

*P.S. It is working fine on iOS 12.x*

I have also posted the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142002576) on the google issue tracker.

Comment: Did you find solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

When you restart your app, the setting `mapView.isMyLocationEnable` is set to false.